Using Python Watchdog to listen to Sharepoint file
Is it possible to use watchdog to accurately listen to a sharepoint file and do operations based on the events there?
Right now, when a new file is added via Teams and synced to the Sharepoint file, the listener does not recognize it as 'on_created', it doesn't recognize at all. Only when the file is moved from the directory that is being listened to, the listener recognizes it as an 'on_deleted' operation.
However, when I create a dummy file on my desktop, and move it to the directory that is being listened, then it is able to recognize.
Edit: I've found a solution where if you choose the "Always keep on this device" option (when you right click on the directory you're listening), it will recognize the correct operations. In case anyone has the same problem, I hope this helps.
